# Configuration auto reloading with pthreads

Tags: pthreads

I am writing multi threaded program in C, currently I need to restart the program every time I make a change to the configuration file, my application also support the standard SIGHUP signal to reload the configuration, but this need manual intervention.

To solve this, I wrote a separate thread that read the configuration file and load it, and keep monitoring this file for any changes.

The question is, how to notify other threads about a configuration change safely and without affecting the performance with huge mutex locks.

I am thinking of having a version number for each configuration change, this way I would only need to lock config_ver variable changes, and keep old configurations accessible for slower threads.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gcc atomic operations you can quickly test if a config changed (time to compare two ints) and you can load new configs...ALL WITHOUT LOCKING.

Psuedo code:

Lets say I had a configuration struct C.  Let there be a global variable _pConfig which points to the current config.

```
struct C *_pConfig;
```

to load a new config:

```
// allocate a new struct C
struct C *pNewconfig = malloc(sizeof(struct C));
...
// load the pNewconfig struct from disk or something
...

// let the config struct have a next pointer so we can save list of configs for freeing later
pNewconfig->pNext = _pConfig;  

// when done loading pNewconfig. change the global.  not before done!, else threads see unf data!
// 32 bit assignment is atomic (usually).  
// If not atomic on your platform, use __sync_bool_compare_and_swap()
_pConfig = pNewConfig;

// is safe to free old cfgs with 0 use counts.  Make sure old is old enough so that there is no chance
// a thread could have been swapped out anywhere between point A and B below (next code section).  
for (struct C *pCfg=pNewconfig->pNext ; pCfg ; pCfg=pCfg->pNext) {
  // Free last pcfg (!pCfg->pNext) if its not in use and its old enough.
  // Don't have to atomically check cUse here since once it changes to zero, its zero forever.
  // nBirthday could be clock ticks when the config was created.  nNow could be ticks now.
  if (!pCfg->pNext && !pCfg->cUse && pCfg->nBirthDay-nNow > OldEnough) {  
    free(pCfg);
    break;
  }
}
```

Now how do we use this...  Each thread needs to keep a ptr to struct C the thread was configured with.  If _pConfig changes, each thread can tell by comparing the thread's struct C address to the current one.  Assume pthread is a pointer to the thread's data.

```
while (1) {
  // POINT A
  struct C *pConfig = _pConfig; // make a copy in case it changes
  // super quick check with no locking!
  if (pConfig == pThread->pConfig) 
    break;  // no change...get out quick.
  __sync_add_and_fetch(&pConfig->cUse, 1); // increment use count of new cfg
  // POINT B
   __sync_sub_and_fetch(&pThread->pConfig->cUse, 1);  // decriment use count of thread's cfg
   pThread->pConfig = pConfig;  // use new cfg
   // do whatever you do with the cfg data
}
```

Use __sync_add, _sub because multiple threads can be accessing the new config at the same time and this ensures an accurate use count.

Be aware of the stall time of a thread scheduled out between point A and B.  Since a time slice is usually 1 ms, a long stall might be a 10-100 ms, unless the scheduler is hosed.  If your configuration data is small and changes only a couple times an hour, I might hold onto it for days before freeing it.  Pick a big enough time that you know there are no stalled threads.  Don't worry if a thread for some reason hasn't checked for a new config in a long time...the use count will be > 1 and it wont be freed.

Comment: The reference counting is probably overkill if you wait long enough before freeing the old configs...or don't free them at all.  The important concept to this solution is you make a new config structure allowing threads to still use the old one until they notice the change.